# What exactly is a quasi-likelihood model?

Tags: generalized-estimating-equations, quasi-likelihood, quasi-maximum-likelihood

I tried reading Wedderburn (1974) http://matt-wand.utsacademics.info/webStatSem/Wedderburn.pdf but I'm not wrapping my head around exactly what quasi-likelihood model is, in particular with generalized estimating equations.  I understand that GEE extends GLM, but what is it about GEE that makes it quasi-like?

Comment: Real likelihoods are the same as joint densities. You usually get those by assuming independence, and just multiplying a bunch of marginal distributions together. You call this a likelihood and maximize it by picking good parameters. Estimating equations do not assume any specific probability distribution. Rather, they just behave like (log-)likelihoods do. That's why it's "quasi"